# Freemarker - behavior of Built-ins with Iterables

Tags: size, freemarker, iterable

I am observing strange behavior with Freemarker.
I have an `Iterable` in `reportModel.affectedJars`. It is provided from a graph database - Tinkerpop/Titan.

```
${iterableHasContent(reportModel.affectedJars)?then("true", "false")}<br>
${reportModel.affectedJars?has_content?then("yes", "no")} has_content<br>
${reportModel.affectedJars?size}<br>
${reportModel.affectedJars}<br>
<#if reportModel.affectedJars?size == 0>
    <p>No archives containing CVE vulnerabilities were found.</p>
<#else>
    <#list reportModel.affectedJars.iterator() as file>
        Something...
```

`iterableHasContent` is an alternative of `?size`.
I would expect this to  be quite consistent, in terms of:

```
false
no has_content
0
<p>No archives ...
```

But what is actually happening is:

```
false
yes has_content
6
--- and no iterations. ---
```

Which looks like there's some glitch that makes Freemarker think that the `Iterable` is not empty, but then when iterated, it gives no items. No exception is thrown.

I was trying to debug, but the debugger doesn't stop at the relevant code for some reason.

Is there something I am missing in `?size` and `?has_content` paradigms that allows this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try do anything with that `Iterable`, except calling `iterator()` on it. The problem is that FreeMarker was created before `Iterable` was introduced, and it sees a pure `Iterable` (i.e., one which doesn't also implement `Collection`) as a generic object, rather than some listable thing. (Fixing this without breaking backward compatibility is not possible, though surely there should be a configuration option for it.) This is also where the size 6 comes from; it's the number of items in the hash, which contains its methods and JavaBean properties. Ugh...

So after you got the `Itera*tor*`, the next thing you will find that it doesn't support `?size`. It supports `?has_content` though. (This assumes that you are using the default object wrapper, not pure `BeansWrapper`, which is pure evil.) But if you can, use `#list` with a nested `#else`. Something like:

```
<#list reportModel.affectedJars.iterator() as file>
    Something...
<#else>
    <p>No archives containing CVE vulnerabilities were found.</p>
</#list>
```

or a more real life example:

```
<#list reportModel.affectedJars.iterator()>
    <p>Found some archives containing CVE vulnerabilities:</p>
    <#items as file>
       Something...
    </#items>
<#else>
    <p>No archives containing CVE vulnerabilities were found.</p>
</#list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extended info! I figured out too after some debugging. Any plans for some Freemarker for Java 8? Or perhaps put the bits that would break Java 1.4 compatibility to some kind of plugin?

Comment: The backward compatibility issue is unrelated to the Java version (and since 2.3.24 FreeMarker requires Java 1.5). It's about the behavior of existing templates. What do you mean by FreeMarker for Java 8? Supporting `Optional` maybe?

Comment: By support for newer Java versions I mean mainly what can be consumed by <#list>, ?size (where applicable), ?has_content etc. For instance, Java 8 streams.

Comment: Streams is a good point. There's no technical obstacle there, except that these most certainly will have to be opt-in features, because existing templates can behave differently because of them. It's merely the question of development resources.

Comment: Right, Iterables, then Streams. I'd like to be of help here. Freemarker is the only usable generic templating enginge for Java (FWICT), so it would deserve some more contributors. Maybe later this year.

Comment: BTW - is there some jira for these? So we can move the discussion to there... or I can specify and create

Comment: Feel free to open an issue for it! One for `Iterable`, another for `Stream` preferably.

Comment: I have committed `Iterable` support into what will become to 2.3.25: https://github.com/apache/incubator-freemarker/commit/f084603d7d9f76ae5bf0536d2ac6af2041a8db5d